# CSS3 @media print - auto "save as PDF"

Tags: google-chrome, printing, media-queries

When printing from Chrome I want to be able to target the destination so that when the print options open it is automatically set to "save as PDF".

Is there a way this can be done, e.g.

```
@media print {
    destination: "save as PDF";


}
```

Thanks